# What mode is Solr 7.2.1 running in?

Tags: solr, centos7, solrcloud

Is there a command, similar to 
`/opt/solr/bin/solr version` that will tell you whether Solr is running in SolrCloud or Standalone mode?

I am running Solr 7.2.1 on Centos7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current system state is available at the REST endpoint `/solr/admin/info/system`. You're looking for the `mode` entry, which [will be `solrcloud` in cluster mode and `std` in regular, non-cloud mode](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/SystemInfoHandler.java#L136).

Comment: This gives a more concise solution than the other suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the link to where this is documented?

Comment: @KaiSchneider As far as I know the actual response from the endpoints isn't documented anywhere, except as the reference to the actual source where this behavior is implemented, as linked in the answer. The endpoints themselves are listed in the implicit request handler definition list: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/implicit-requesthandlers.html#available-implicit-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

why not something simple like:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/zookeeper?detail=true&path=%2Fclusterstate.json
```

and check that it returns some valid json?

Comment: That's probably the best I'll get. Without zookeeper running it returns an HTTP 500 error:
Problem accessing /solr/admin/zookeeper. Reason:

    {trace=java.lang.NullPointerException